# Firebase best practice for counting lists

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on a cross-platform firebase project that shows data in certain lists. I am using the official firebase documentation about showing lists of data, but I could not find anything about keeping count.

Is it recommended to store count in the database or rather to count the amount of entries with a snapshot? If the answer should be: in the database, then how can I manage that ?

Documentation reference:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data

Comment: just change to Firestore  :/

Comment: Is this question answered in firestore documentation? If so, can you link it ?